# Monitor Users actions in windows server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, monitoring

I have 25 users connected remotely to my server , is there a way to monitor all users actions , its not a problem if there is a third party program .

Monitor means file auditing , visited sites , any change in system settings .

Any help please or any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a good server monitoring software. I see no problem at all as there are many tools e.g.[Anturis](http://www.anturis.com), Pingdom, New Relic etc. They offer more or less the same options, but the price will be different depending on the tool. Some of them provide an agent which monitors the whole work of a server and it doesn't influence its work in any way. Choose what suits you better.